# To calculate an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx$$
finite? How to solve this?

Comment: Does there any other easier way to do that

Comment: Whats the logarithmic base of this? You also just can substitute t=ln(x) to this one and then put integration by parts then this will be solved.

Comment: It turns out that it is finite(by integration by parts). Is that correct?

Comment: I think you done this in my way. May be you have to find the value of $-e^t(t+1)$ when t goes to infinity. So then use the L hopital rule for that. Then you will get it is equals to 0. So then substitute it and then you will get this integrals value as 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We integrate by parts

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx &= \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\int_{1}^{t}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(\left[-\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right]_{1}^{t}-\int_{1}^{t}-\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\text{ }dx\right)\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(1)}{1}-\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-\int_{1}^{t}-\frac{1}{x^2}dx\right)\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(-\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]_{1}^{t}\right)\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(-\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{1}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-\frac{1}{t}\right)
\end{align*}

As $t\to\infty$, $\frac{\ln(t)}{t}$ and $\frac{1}{t}$ both tend to $0$, so

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\ln(t)}{t}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the $\log$, then you can turn it back to exponent by setting $u = \log x \implies x = e^u\implies dx = e^udu\implies I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty ue^{-2u}(e^{u}du)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty ue^{-u}du= -\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty ud(e^{-u})=- \left(ue^{-u}|_{u=0}^\infty-\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}du\right)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}du = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t= \ln x.$ When we differentiate this we get $dt=\frac{1}{x}dx$. Also $e^{t} = x.\Rightarrow \color{red}A$

By $\color{red}A$ we get $e^{t}dt=dx\Rightarrow \color{red}B$.
So by substituting $\color{red}B$ we get,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} te^{-t}dt=\int_{0 }^{\infty} t\frac{d\left [ -e^{-t} \right ]}{dt}dt$$

By integration by parts we get,
$$\int_{0 }^{\infty} te^{-t}dt=\left [ -te^{-t} \right ]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t}dt=\left [ -te^{-t} \right ]_{0 }^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}dt$$

$$\int_{0 }^{\infty} te^{-t}dt=\left [ -te^{-t} \right ]_{1}^{\infty}+\left [ -e^{-t} \right ]_{0}^{\infty}=\left [ -te^{-t}-e^{-t} \right ]_{0}^{\infty}={\infty}=\left [ -e^{-t}(t+1) \right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$

So we have to find $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t}(t+1)$ value,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t}(t+1)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t+1}{e^{t}}$$

So by L'hopital rule,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t}(t+1)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t+1}{e^{t}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{t}}=0$$

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{0 }^{t} te^{-t}dt=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left [ -e^{-t}(t+1) \right ]_{0}^{t}$$
So we get $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{0 }^{t} te^{-t}dt=0+1=1$$

So as our final answer we get,

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx=1$$

I got this as my answer. If there is any miscalculations. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts. Keep trying different parts until it works.

1. This doesn't work:

$u= \frac1x$, $dv=\frac{\ln(x)dx}{x}$

$du= -\frac{dx}{x^2}$, $v=\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2}$

2. This doesn't work:

$u= \frac1{x^2}$, $dv=\frac{\ln(x)}{1}$

$du= (...)$, $v=(...)$

3. This works

$u=\frac{\ln(x)}{1}$, $dv= \frac1{x^2}$

$du=\frac{1}{x}$, $v= -\frac1{x}$

Comment: (+1) the only one that gets rid of the log is the one that works, so I never even considered the other two, but as a general approach, there is nothing wrong with trying other options.

Comment: thank you @robjohn